# How to handle Burst requst in AWS WAF

Tags: amazon-web-services, rate-limiting, aws-application-load-balancer, amazon-waf

There is a use case where we need to implement rate limit for our AWS rest API on ECS .
Initially we have used NLB but because the requirement came to use rate limit so that users can not damage  our AWS resources .
Resource flow is

WAF <--> ALB <-->ECS

We have applied rate limit on WAF but it does not work for us because of its caveats
Below caveats is from AWS Docs on WAF

**The following caveats apply to AWS WAF rate-based rules:**

*AWS WAF checks the rate of requests every 30 seconds, and counts requests for the prior 5 minutes each time. Because of this, it's possible for an IP address to send requests at too high a rate for 30 seconds before AWS WAF detects and blocks it.
AWS WAF can block up to 10,000 IP addresses. If more than 10,000 IP addresses send high rates of requests at the same time, AWS WAF will only block 10,000 of them.*

Our users port request in bulk ,Like 4K request is submitted within 10 seconds and that bypasses WAF rule .

We can not use AWS API gateway because our response can be more than 10 MB also and integration time out is also 30 seconds but our can go upto some time 1 minutes .

Is there any other way that we can be used here apart from application based rate limiting ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following approach:

1. Put CloudFront in front of the ALB
2. Configure WAF with rate-limiting on CloudFront instead
3. Restrict access to the ALB to CloudFront only
4. Enable caching on CloudFront (GET, HEAD and OPTIONS requests)

This way if there is a spike in GET request to your application, CloudFront will send a response directly from cache. The request will not hit the ALB nor it will hit your ECS service(s).

Answer (score 0):

The AWS Solutions Library includes a [Security Automations for AWS WAF](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/security-automations-for-aws-waf/) solution that might directly meet your needs or provide a blueprint that you can adapt to your specific situation. One component of the solution is HTTP flood protection:

[image: AWS]

The high-level design of the solution’s flood protection:

- [capture WAF traffic for analysis](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/logging.html)
- analyze the traffic according to the enabled set of protections using Lambda & Athena
- dynamically update the WAF rulesets in response to request floods or other unwanted behavior

[The full solution from AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/security-automations-for-aws-waf/architecture-overview.html) includes 8 separate components which can be configured at implementation time.

You can also [use the source of the solution as a reference](https://github.com/aws-solutions/aws-waf-security-automations) to implement your own approach if the AWS architecture doesn’t quite fit your use case.

There is also an earlier implementation of parts of this solution [available in the AWS WAF Samples repository](https://github.com/amazon-archives/aws-waf-sample).